# Generating Control Flow Graph for c++ source files in Windows

Tags: windows, c++

Currently, I am conducting a research that involves analyzing the c++ source files. For that reason, I have to make the **control flow graph** of c++ files. I just wanted to know if there is an open source **control flow graph generation tool** exist which I can run on c++ source files. And more specifically if it's possible to run the tool on **Windows OS**.

On the internet, I have found many related questions and answers, but unfortunately not any one of them satisfies what I need. Any idea/link would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify your price limit and which features you are missing / what are your needs for the tools you already checked and which tols you checked.

Comment: Not open source, so I'm not posting this an answer to your requirements.   But generates CF graphs for MS C++, GCC and Clang C++, runs on Windows.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html